# Workbook_NewSheet(Byval Sh as Object)

Tags: excel, vba

I have implemented 2 different levels of authorized access to ThisWorkbook. Level 1 only allows the user to modified a specific visible worksheet and does not authorize him/her to do anything else, including adding a new worksheet. (And level 2 users are allowed to see everything and do anything to the workbook).

My problem is how to prevent level 1 user from trying to create a new sheet. I am attempting to use "Workbook_NewSheet" event to handle this event by immediately deleting this sheet the moment it is created. However, the argument "Sh" is passed by value, and as an "Object", not "Worksheet". I can't modify (or deleting) this "Byval" object.

Anyone has any advice?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by protect the workbook with password

protecting the structure of a workbook will prevent users from Inserting new worksheets or chart sheets.
[Password protect worksheet or workbook elements](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Password-protect-worksheet-or-workbook-elements-dbf706e0-ba22-4a08-84d8-552db16eef11)

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I will try implementing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to `Sh` like below. The code below turns off alerts, deletes the newly created sheet, and then turns alerts back on.

`Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sh.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could you explain why this "Byval" variable "Sh" is modified even though it is not passed "Byref"?